# How to assign file content into a variable in Java

Tags: java, file, variables

I have a .txt file in various variables are there(each are separated by a line). I need to read .txt file and assign it to corresponding variables as in txt file.
**No need to be in same order**

input.txt

```
int a=3;
boolean b=true;
String sr = "Hai";
```

what I tried

```
int a;
boolean b;
String sr;
String CurrentLine;
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\input.txt"));
while ((CurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    \\ need to read assign variables to corresponding variables in test file
}
```

**Is is possible to declarer variables in file and read in main()?**

Comment: What doesn't work with what you tried?

Comment: Integer.parseInt(currentLine) for int, currentLine.equalsIgnoreCase("true") for boolean, curretLine as String for String data type

Comment: @dotvav how can I assign a string to string and int to int ...

Comment: @sunrise76 Thankyou how can I read when I have multiple variables with int and how can I assign specific specific ??

Comment: Is it possible to declare in file and read in program ??

Comment: Change  file format to JSON/XML form. Without the structure to the data, you can't read it

Comment: May be you should try a standart java properties file and it's API, and avoi to set a data type for variables, if it's not necessary

Comment: Why declaring the type of the variable in your txt file? The type is fixed in your Java code, so you already know how to read it. I agree with @Stanislav and his proposal about `Properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is an option, I suggest you change your file format as follows:

**input.properties**

```
a=3
b=true
sr=Hai
```

And use a code like the following:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(new FileInputStream("intput.properties"));
int a = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("a", "0"));
boolean b = Boolean.parseBoolean(prop.getProperty("b", "false"));
String sr = prop.getProperty("sr");
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like this (but it is awfaul, brittle code without any form of exception handling):

```
    if (CurrentLine.startsWith("boolean")) {
        String str = CurrentLine.substring(0, CurrentLine.length()-1);
        String[] sa = str.split("=");
        b = Boolean.parseBoolean(sa[1].trim());
    }
    else if (CurrentLine.startsWith("int"))
    //...
```

As mentionend in the comments you should use some structured file format, if possible.